# Update if a specific one of several exists, insert otherwise

Tags: php, mysql

I have read through dozens of posts covering ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but so far none of these have covered my specific use case. Here is my simple code at the moment:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO $DatabaseName .`scores` (`id`, `name`, `score` , `score2`)
    VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$score', '$score2');";
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    name='$name', score='$score', score2='$score2',
```

I have another script which monitors a user's "highest score" and compares it to their "current score". If the "current score" gets higher than the "highest score" it triggers the above code.

By default the user's details are then inserted into the database (since it may not exist yet). But if an entry with that 'name' already exists, I would like to update the 'score' and 'score2' only (the 'id' and 'name' should stay unchanged). Note that I need to specifically check for a 'name' duplicate here, since if the 'score' or 'score2' are the same as an existing entry it doesn't matter.

Is this possible with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, or will I need to fetch specific fields and use conditionals? I would prefer not to if possible.

Comment: Do u have a unique-constraint on "name"?

Comment: If I understand correctly, 'name' is a unique index in your DB schema. Or, at least, should be. If this is the case, there should be no problem because the INSERT for an existing 'name' triggers the DUPLICATE KEY and you may update the score values.

Comment: I don't actually have a unique constraint on 'name'. When I run my above code using a value for 'name' that already exists nothing is inserted, or at least the existing row stays unchanged.

Comment: This is strange, because if 'name' is not unique, the INSERT should create a new row. This is why it should be unique ;)
The unchanged scores are no surprise, because there is no duplicate key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you add the UNIQUE index on the `name` column:

```
ALTER TABLE `scores` ADD UNIQUE `name_unique` (`name`);
```

And no need to insert a NULL id, or update the name column:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $DatabaseName .`scores` (`name`,`score`,`score2`)
          VALUES ('$name', '$score', '$score2')
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score='$score', score2='$score2'";
```

And also, you should use a prepared statement instead of putting php variables directly in the request.